# Convert xml to mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Is there a way to convert an xml file to a mysql table as a sql statement using php?

I'm open to any PEAR packages you know of.

Comment: reference for myself [mysql xml](http://www.w3cgallery.com/w3c-blog/php-mysql-ajax-hacks-trick/how-to-store-simplexml-parse-value-into-session-or-mysql-by-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, parsing XML to MySQL is a direct task and need a lot customization based on your XML structure. I suggest you to use SimpleXML to parse XML and insert into MySQL using PHP's MySQLi classes.

Comment: could you post a quick sample I just want to see a way to go through a certain number of records and input them as mysql

Answer (score 1):

there are several packages available to read XML data in PHP (parsing XML). You can write simple code to insert the same in mysql with your custom fields.

I used ParseXml.class.php from phpclasses.org

The code should use like below.

```
require './ParseXml.class.php';

 $xml = new ParseXml();
 $xml->LoadFile("./test.xml");
 //$xml->LoadString($xmlString);
 //$xml->LoadRemote("http"//www.yourdomain.com/dir/filename.xml", 3);
 $dataArray = $xml->ToArray();
```